# Simulation of ball movement in a 3d landscape. The easiest way?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, physics, game-physics

I have a landscape(generated via Perlin noise) and a ball. I want the ball to move along the geodesic(implementation of basic physics: gravitation, friction). 
I thought to do raycast around the ball to the landscape, choose the lowest point and move the ball to this point, but it won't work in every case and it won't allow the ball to jump (with inertia).
So, what is the best way/algorithm to implement such feature?

P.S. I don't want to use any libraries.

Comment: This is very, very difficult. Don't forget to consider the energy due to the ball's rotation. (Can you recall what the moment of inertia of a sphere is?). Also, what happens at a step? How will you decide if the ball will mount the step? I think you need to amend the question with a list of specific things you do and don't want to model. And set quite a bit of time aside for this.

Comment: I didn't -1 your question but almost. You don't say if it's for game, or physics school project, or for impress a girl... you should better start in 2D especially for a school project if you have to do it from scratch. I wrote myself some project from scratch, you should start by having good knowledge of physics (see classical mechanic - taylor). A good teacher that you can harass AND a good math library (eg Armadillo) NEVER TRY to write a matrix solver by yourself (personnal bad experience). Otherwise use a physics library like bullet.

Comment: If the ball is rolling down a very steep hill, the collision point won't be "down" from the center, it will be nearly horizontally out from the center, so you might want to revise your idea of using a ray cast.  When the ball rolls into a narrow, steep sided valley it is likely to touch on both sides but not at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll take some time, but it's not THAT hard, you need to calculate the ball's new position, ignoring the height field at all (only gravity & inertia) and then, after this step, you check for collisions (basic collision detection between sphere and triangle mesh), and if a collision is detected, generate the collision data and resolve it by applying an impulse OR force in the appropriate direction, using the motion direction and the collision normal direction. Now, if you never worked with collision detection before, it'll probably take you some extra time to learn the algorithms involved, like how to detect collision, how to generate the collision data (normal, penetration, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own physics library for this task which individual effort can take months. If you still don't want to export an external engine to your project, At least I suggest you to check open-source engines to see how they handle things.

I can suggest [Bullet Physics](https://code.google.com/p/bullet/) for a start.